# Axios post request in Gatsbyjs

Tags: reactjs, axios, gatsby

I have blogsite using gatsbyjs template and I have a newsletter feature which is sending the user's email.
so basically Im using axios post request in sending emails.

Im wondering if the axios will work perfectly fine in gatsby in live site after build?
Isnt the gatsby is building a static files? does the axios still work?

Comment: i think as mentioned in the docs, it will work with axios and also you can use native fetch also. https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/data-fetching/

Comment: I'm guessing you are posting some data (using axios) to a backend service which is sending the newsletter. It's a bit unclear how your build looks. Axios is just a a helper library to make it easier to create requests client-side but you can just use fetch. In the end, Gatsby is just a React app in the end, so you can use anything that works in React.

Comment: Thanks guys! :) DILEEPTHOMAS & Albert Skibinski

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will work, you have many `axios` [examples](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-search-with-js-search/#js-search-with-a-small-to-medium-dataset) across Gatsby's docs.

Gatsby generates JS files, so executing `axios` code won't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you Dennis Vash.
A big help to me :)

Answer (score 2):

Of course, it will work, Gatsby generates and compiles all files when you deploy it (or running the build command); this means that it takes the content (and data) from all sources (using GraphQL) and generates a static HTML file with a bundled JavaScript file, which doesn't mean that you cannot have asynchronous data fetching or asynchronous functions to do whatever you do. It's just a page-generation.

Afterward, if you want to load asynchronously all your content with Axios (for example), you are capable to achieve this, however, you will be losing the potential of Gatsby. Indeed, your site will be a React-based site so you have all that Gatsby offers in terms of page generation + React features.

So, all your JavaScript functions will trigger when you want (`onClick`, `useEffect`, `componentDidMount`, etc). Here's a screenshot about how Gatsby works in terms of data fetching.

[image]

The only thing you need to take into account is when using third-party libraries to not load into your Webpack configuration (because some libraries need the `window` to be defined at the build time, and with Gatsby, you don't) but it is perfectly handled in [their documentation](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/docs/docs/debugging-html-builds.md).